# Добавление шума к данным

Tags: машинное-обучение

Написал для себя маленькую нейронку для распознавания цифр из базы MNIST (from scratch так сказать). С готовыми данными справляется нормально, но когда я хочу распознавать свои рукописные цифры, получаются ошибки - [тут объснили почему](https://youtu.be/hfMk-kjRv4c?t=2646). Хотел спросить, а на какие матрицы мне умножать картинку, чтобы получить сдвиг цифры или ее поворот?

[image: вывод моей программы]

Comment: Удалите метку [обработка-данных]. Она слишком общая и сейчас сжигается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, пока вопрос лежал, нашел ответы на него сам.
Привожу код

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import ImageEnhance, Image

data = pd.read_csv('....digit-recognizer\train.csv')

data = np.array(data)
image = data[1][1:]
    

def add_some_noise(image):
    
    image.shape = (28,28)
    
    image = image / 1
    
    temp_file = Image.fromarray(image).convert('L')
    temp_size = np.random.randint(10,35)
    temp_file = temp_file.resize((temp_size,temp_size))
    
    image = np.array(temp_file.crop((temp_file.size[0] / 2 - 14, temp_file.size[1] / 2 - 14, temp_file.size[1] / 2 + 14, temp_file.size[1] / 2 + 14)))
    
    
    temp_file = ndimage.rotate(image, random.randint(-20, 20), reshape=False, prefilter=False) / 1
    temp_file = Image.fromarray(temp_file).convert("L")
    
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(temp_file)
    factor = np.random.random(1)[0] * 10
    temp_file = enhancer.enhance(factor)
    image = np.array(temp_file)
    
    image = np.roll(image, random.randint(-4,4), axis = 1)
    image = np.roll(image, random.randint(-2,2), axis = 0)
    
    pixels = [250, 150,  100, 50 , 0]
    noise = np.random.choice(pixels, 784,  p=[0.003, 0.005,  0.007,  0.015, 0.97])

    noise.shape = (28,28)

    image = image + (1 * image < 50) * noise
    
    image.shape = (1,784)
    
    return image[0]
```

```
image = image / 1
```

метод fromarray почему-то работает c float, но не int

```
    temp_file = Image.fromarray(image).convert('L')
    temp_size = np.random.randint(10,35)
    temp_file = temp_file.resize((temp_size,temp_size))
    
    image = np.array(temp_file.crop((temp_file.size[0] / 2 - 14, temp_file.size[1] / 2 - 14, temp_file.size[1] / 2 + 14, temp_file.size[1] / 2 + 14)))
```

Изменяю рандомно размер изображения и потом делаю вырез 28x28

```
temp_file = scipy.ndimage.rotate(image, random.randint(-20, 20), reshape=False, prefilter=False) / 1
```

Поворот изображения. Деление на 1, чтобы совпали типы данных. (возвращает картинку)

```
temp_file = Image.fromarray(temp_file).convert("L")
```

массив из картинки

```
factor = np.random.random(1)[0] * 10
temp_file = enhancer.enhance(factor)
image = np.array(temp_file)
```

изменяем резкость или размываем

```
image = np.roll(image, random.randint(-2,2), axis = 0)
```

сдвиг по осям

```
pixels = [250, 150,  100, 50 , 0]
noise = np.random.choice(pixels, 784,  p=[0.003, 0.005,  0.007,  0.015, 0.97])

noise.shape = (28,28)

image = image + (1 * image < 100) * noise
```

добавление шума

```
(1 * image < 100) * noise
```

именно в те места, где не изображена сама цифра

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще, очень классно, что доступно там много инструментов на python)

Comment: Молодец, что разобрались. Да, обычно используют повороты, сдвиги, шум. В некоторых случаях ещё отражение (если кошки-собачки, например), но в случае цифр отражение не нужно, тут ориентация фиксированная. Так то ещё бывает используют размытие, сдвиг яркости, ну, много чего можно придумать. Всё это расширяет базу обучения.

Comment: Да, замечание: код в вопросах и ответах должен быть со всеми импортами! Сейчас чтобы запустить ваш код нужно самому догадаться, какие библиотеки и как подключить. А это бывает нелегко. Добавьте все нужные импорты в код. Код должен быть самодостаточным для запуска. В случае, если всё нужное есть в вопросе и в ответе приводятся только изменения код, импорты можно не приводить. Но только в этом случае.

Comment: @CrazyElf а могу ли я первоначальные и зашумленные данные использовать вместе, дабы увеличить выборку? Если да, то большой ли имеет смысл так делать?

Comment: А что за модели то? Для таких картинок, которые со свигами, нужно уже сети со слоями `CNN` строить, с пуллингом и т.д., т.е. с поиском определённых фрагментов на картинке и их сочетаний. Сети, которые угадывают цифры по наличию сигнала **в конкретной ячейке сетки** на зашумлённых данных естественно работать уже не будут. Кроме того, нужно смотреть глазами, как вы картинки зашумили. Может какие-то методы портят картинку настолько, что в ней уже невозможно признаки найти )  Но это можно увидеть только если глазами посмотреть. Такие преобразования лучше убрать.

Comment: Да, конечно, весь смысл именно в том, что зашумлённые картинки дополняют данные для обучения, а не заменяют их. Хотя, смотря как именно зашумлять. Зависит от конкретики. Да, и ещё нужно помнить, что на `MNIST` невозможна метрика 100%, потому что там есть некоторое количество картинок, которым нельзя однозначно лейбл проставить, либо он там вообще неправильно проставлен. 100% можно получить только моделью, которая прямо вот запомнит лейблы этих неправильных картинок (что не есть хорошо).

Comment: @CrazyElf самые простые с прямолинейным проходом, которые вручную можно реализовать.  Ну что ж, если не получится с такими, буду дальше изучать тему и пробовать реализовывать, авось получится) Вдохновился видео - https://youtu.be/hfMk-kjRv4c , захотел также сделать. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Для простых моделей шум губителен. Да даже просто сдвиг. Поэтому CNN и придумали для картинок )

Comment: @CrazyElf вроде получилось) обучил до 82% и теперь не угадывает мои рукописи только иногда. Жаль здесь нельзя картинками поделиться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149269/discussion-between--and-crazyelf).

Comment: В ответ можно добавлять картинки )